# Google Sheets - Return "Yes" or "No" if 3 criteria across 3 different columns are found

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm wondering if there is a formula that can return "Yes" after searching 3 columns and finding 3 exact matches, or "No" if not.

For example, I'd search Column A for "Lizzie", Column D for "10", and Column E for "Approved" and would like "Yes" returned if all 3 values are found in relevant columns, and "No" returned if only 1 or 2 or less are found

[image: 1]

The issue is I can't specify which cell exactly to look in e.g. A278 for Lizzie, as due to filtering on the sheet the value in the cell may change position.

I tried the following but it returns "N" even when "Lizzie", "Approved" and "10" are all in relevant columns, but I'm not sure what the workaround is:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!A:A="Lizzie",Sheet1!E:E="Approved",Sheet1!D:D="10"),"Y","N")
```

The context behind this search is so I can see who has proofread and approved certain pages of a catalogue in a simple table which will be formatted as such:

[image: 2]

Comment: Would they not have to be the same rows?

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. However in this case due to filtering on the sheet, the values in the rows might move/change so specifying exact cells won't work I don't think. Not sure if there's a workaround in this case...

Comment: Please rework title and tags to show this question is about Google-Sheets (according to your screenshots) and not Excel.

Comment: Sorry, tags all fixed now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample setup as in your screenshot and you may have to adapt it to your design

formula in `cell H3` for Lizzie:

```
=INDEX(IF(LEN(H$2:$2),IF(ISERROR(HLOOKUP(G3&H$2:$2&"Approved",TRANSPOSE(A:A&D:D&E:E),1,)),"N","Y"),))
```

- 

[image]